# Start service after mount/luks open

Tags: systemd, mount, luks, volume

I have a luks encrypted volume.
On this volume are qemu/libvirt disks stored.

Now when the server boots, qemu/libvirt cant start because the volume is not available/mounted.

Is there a way to tell systemd/qemu to start libvirt only after i have manually mounted the volume?

I have tried to add `After=mnt-volumexyz.mount` to the libvirtd service file, but that didnt work.

*Note: that there is no fstab entry for the volume.*